# Is the function $f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \tfrac{a_n}{n} \sin(n\pi x)$ absolutely continuous on $[0, 1]$?

Tags: fourier-series, absolute-continuity

Let $f \colon [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n} \sin(n\pi x), 
$$
for some square-summable real sequence $a_n$.

Is it true that $f$ is absolutely continuous? I tried a basic estimate,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^K |f(u_k) - f(v_k)| \leq \sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{k \leq K} \frac{|a_n|}{n} |\sin(n \pi u_k) - \sin(n\pi v_k)|
\lesssim 
\delta \sum_{n \geq 1} |a_n|,  
$$
provided that $\sum_k |u_k - v_k| \leq \delta$, however this does not seem to be strong enough.

Is there another argument? Or is this not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\sum a_n \cos (n\pi x)$. In view of the orthogonality of $(\cos (n \pi x))$ it follows that $g$ is a well defined $L^{2}$ function. Hence $g \in L^{1}$ and $\int_0^{x} g(t)dt$ is absolutely continuous. But $\int_0^{x} g(t)dt=\frac  1 {\pi} f(x)$, so $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: it’s nice to note that this reasoning extends also to the case where $(a_n)\subset \ell^p(\Bbb{N})$, for some $p\in [1,\infty)$, and that in this case $g\in L^p([0,1])\subset L^1([0,1])$, and so $f$ is both AC and Holder-continuous of exponent $1-\frac{1}{p}$.

Comment: I guess one has $\int (g_N - g)^2 \asymp \sum_{n > N} a_n^2 \to 0$, which implies that $\int |g_N - g| \to 0$, which implies $\lim_N \int g_N = \int g$ and so one obtains $\int g = \lim_N \int g_N \asymp \lim_N f_N = f$, as required. Let me know if this reasoning is correct!

Comment: (I use $\asymp$ to denote that I am dropping a constant)

Comment: Sorry, that I was not loged in for quite some time. Everything you are saying is correct. @DrewBrady

Comment: I don't think DCT is correct here, though. It seems you need to directly use the $L^2 \subset L^1$ inclusion specific to $[0, 1]$ or a finite measure space? See my argument above?

Comment: DCT is not required; $L^{2}$ convergence is enough . When I said 'Everything you are saying is correct' I was referring to your first comment above. @DrewBrady